# Dynamic tables: change # of rows depending on available width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, html-table

I need to make a set of floated left tables dynamic with page re-size.
Instead of:
[image]

I want this to happen:
[image]
The general structure is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr title="Static title">
                <td class="indicator">Static text</td>
                <td class="val">Text retrieved from ajax call</td>
            </tr>
            ...<tr>...</tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
    ...<table>...</table>
</div>
```

That is, I have multiple tables and each one contains multiple rows. My css ensures that each table is the width of its widest row:

```
table, td.indicator {float: left;}
td {display: inline-block;}
td.val{
   float: right;
   padding-left: 5px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I also have a javascript/jQuery function that generates this html:

```
function genFundamentalsHTML(rows){
    s = '<table><tbody>';               
    $.each(d.indicators, function(index, value) {
        s += '<tr title="' + value.title + '">';
        if ((index+1)<= rows){
            s += '<td class="indicator firstInd">' + value.name + '</td>';
        } else {
            s += '<td class="indicator">' + value.name + '</td>';   
        }
        s += '<td class="val">' + value.val + '</td>';
        s += '</tr>';
        if ((index+1)% rows == 0){
            s += '</tbody></table><table><tbody>';
        } 
    });                 
    s += '</tbody></table><div class="clear"></div>';                   
    $('#wrapper').html(s);
}
```

I have another function that calculates and applies the correct left padding to all td.indicator elements so that the tables always fill the entire width of the wrapper. My problem is that when you decrease the screen width, since the tables are floated left, when their combined width is greater than that of the wrapper, the ones on the end jump below and the layout immediately becomes uneven. Instead, when a certain threshold of padding on the td.indicator elements is reached, say 5px, I would like to increase the number of rows per table. In fact, I have achieved this but only on page refresh by simply hardcoding some if statements checking wrapper width and calling genFundamentalsHTML(rows) with a hardcoded parameter 7,9,12,etc. I attempted to modify my padding function so that it would regenerate the tables html depending on padding width, but that led no where and even caused the page to crash/get stuck at a smaller width than the browser(?):

```
window.r = 7;
function spaceIndicators() {
    var spacing = ($('wrapper').width() - insideWidth) / numCol;

    $('td.indicator').css({'padding-left' : parseInt(spacing) + 'px'});
    $('.firstInd').css({'padding-left' : '0px'});

    if(parseInt(spacing)<= 5){
        r += 1;
        genFundamentalsHTML(r);
        fillValues();
    }
    if(parseInt(spacing)>24){
        r -= 1;
        genFundamentalsHTML(r);
        fillValues();
    }
}
```

If I comment out the second block, the page actually becomes responsive, adding more rows as the width is decreased. However, when you expand again nothing changes (and I would like it to go back to the correct number of rows).

**How do I create a table system with dynamic number of rows depending on available width to fill?**

PS. One idea I had was to loop through the process, calculating insideWidth, and if it was larger than the wrapper width then redo it with rows += 1 until you get an insideWidth less than wrapper width. The problem with this is my values are retrieved from an api and so I would have to reload all that data each time I want to see what the insideWidth is.

Comment: set the width of the block to a percentage (25%), not to pixels.

Comment: I'm not setting the width to pixels, the width is dependent on the content which is fetched from an api; I can't know the width of each table until the content is added. And besides, how would that dynamically add/remove rows?